# Quit current dialog if user wants to stop

Tags: frameworks, bots, azure-language-understanding, mbf

I am using multiple dialogs. Some use formbuilder, some use a ResultAfter method for custom prompting of values. I want a method to check incomming messages on exit words like stop, quit etc.

I thought the StartAsync function would be a good start. Seeing all dialogs are forwarded from my RootDialog I have implemented this in the RootDialog:

```
    public override async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        string[] stopStrings = { "quit", "cancel", "exit" };
        var msg = context.Activity.AsMessageActivity().Text;
        if (stopStrings.Any(msg.Contains))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("You cancelled.");
            context.Done(true);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
    }
```

When I ask the bot to "stop" it succesfully tells me I cancelled. But on the next message I send I get this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
```

At this line in my MessageController:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
```

Now I am not sure what key is not found, and why it sends me this. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when someone wants to accomplish something like this such as a keyword to cancel they use [scorables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).  Scorables are global message handlers so if a keyword you set triggers one it gets handled before firing off your normal dialog flow.  There are some great resources out there for scorables like [this blog](http://www.garypretty.co.uk/2017/04/13/using-scorables-for-global-message-handling-and-interrupt-dialogs-in-bot-framework/) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88) should get you started.

I wasn't actually able to reproduce this error, but here are some tips and thoughts. I don't think I have ever seen someone put logic in `StartAsync` and act as they would expect it to.  I wasn't able to figure out why you are overriding it the way you are when i was trying your code. The logic should be in `MessageReceivedAsync`.  Try moving your logic into the `MessageReceivedAsync` method. Another thing to try if you absolutely want to do it this way it to replace context.Done(true) with just `context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);` since you are in the `RootDialog` anyways, messages will just be routed there from the messages controller and you do not need to manually manipulate the dialog stack, although I do not know the structure of your project so I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using LUIS. I tried to handle the intent "Cancel" which should handle words like exit and stop. This does not work (I have put the intent handling both in the rootdialog and the child dialog). Using Scorable while also using Luis feels a bit odd, or is this general practice? About replacing the .done with a .wait: I want to quit the current (child)dialog. Waiting for a next reply would just forward the message to the child dialog again.

Comment: Using LUIS and a scorable together is a completely legitimate way to design your bot, it is very common for handling things like "back" and "quit".  We actually have a [sample that uses LUIS QnA and scorables all in the same project](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/Luis-Scorable-QnA).  I see what you are saying about the done/wait. It was hard to infer what all was going on in your project with the sample code.